# Problems with scaling text while zooming on browser

Tags: css

basically i have set up my html elements in css with percentages, if i zoom in the elements/boxes stay the same but the text just gets over inflated/gets too big and goes outside the box.

Is there any way to keep the text inside and give it like a max-font-size for zooming in to not allow the text to get too big.

https://gist.github.com/seby1995/751e3eddcd12f24aeb7a

https://gist.github.com/seby1995/faaaf4ee2696aa051737

https://gist.github.com/seby1995/01adf5234cb55cd14a65

Normal:

[image]

Zoomed in:

[image]

Comment: I want to make sure I understand the question. Is it when you change the zoom level in the browser itself, or is it just when you zoom in on the elements/boxes themselves?

Comment: @Spyder_Says_hi when i zoom in on the browser, so for example on chrome if i hold ctrl and use the scroll bar the elements stay the same because of the percentages but the text gets too big.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. Can you include your CSS code of what you have so far? Screenshots will also help. 
Check out [this](https://css-tricks.com/zooming-squishes/) in the mean time.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `em` instead of `px` if you want the fonts/elements to be proportional while resizing browser window

so do this ...

```
<div style="background:blue; width:5em; height:5em;">
  <span style="font-size: 1.7em; color:white;">foobar</span>
</div>
```

and in your browser resize with your keyboard `cmd/ctrl + +` or `cmd/ctrl + -` and you will see that foobar is exactly in the same place inside the box at any size (besides ridiculously minuscule)